# Magmi v0.7.22 import while image name include “fußballschuhe” “ß” disappear front

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

Magmi v0.7.22 import while image name include "fußballschuhe" "ß"(like "cap kinder weiß-563tjs.jpg", "mundial kinder weiß-442bqx.jpg") disappear front,can't import success.the other image name include english style appear well front.anyone can help me,i use the magmi import product with my site sale eruo country.that Germany Czech Language image name will in that situation.

and i can use the magento back import them all well.the magmi i use can't import the image name that include "weiß" or other character likely Germany Czech Language. @Dweeves

Answer (score 0):

I am a long time Magmi user, and never had problems with german or international critical characters in text fields. Just ensure the whole text file is UTF-8 encoded and you're done.

Image names indeed have other pitfalls, e.g. they are processed in Magento methods for scaling, copying and such things. In the end they get sent to the user's webbrowser through the HTML code you generate.

**I recommend making image file names "url friendly" in the Magmi CSV file:**

- replace every non `[0-9A-Za-z]` character to underline `_`
- convert filename to lowercase
- cut filename at 200 characters

Comment: thanks for your answer,the text file is UTF-8 here.just the image name include any critical characters("ß" "weiß"),wile the image can't appear front.

Comment: I test with the Magento Backstage import,it's well for front.